# When trying to connect to redshift through python using psycopg2 module following error is bring displayed

Tags: amazon-redshift, psycopg2

I was getting the following error when I trying to connect to redshift via python and using the psycopg2 module.

```
import psycopg2

my_db = 'dbname'
my_host = 'red-shift hostname'
my_port = '5439'
my_user = 'username'
my_password = 'password'


con = psycopg2.connect(dbname=my_db,host=my_host,port=my_port,user=my_user,password=my_password)
```

Error:

`OperationalError: could not translate host name "redshift://redshift-cluster-1.cqxnjksdfndsjsdf.us-east-2.redshift.amazonaws.com" to address: Unknown host`

Comment: please share your code, what you have tried and improve your formatting.

Comment: Please share your code exactly - not just the error message. e.g. i should be able to replicate your problem by putting in MY redshift details!. please check your url and port, please check you have set up the redshift security group correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar issue. Seems like this is an SSL issue when trying to connect. 
Use [sqlalchemy-redshift](https://github.com/sqlalchemy-redshift/sqlalchemy-redshift) to connect to your redshift cluster, it will work. 
This is how the docs show to connect

`import sqlalchemy as sa
db_uri = 'redshift+psycopg2://username:password@redshift-cluster-1.cqxnxldsfjjbsdc.us-east-2.redshift.amazonaws.com:5439/dbname'
eng = sa.create_engine(db_uri)`